# Primes dividing functions defined by linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, recurrences, conjectures

For Fibonacci numbers $F_n$ it holds that $p|F_{p-(\frac{5}{p})}$, if $p$ is an odd prime (Legendre symbol).
I guessed that the number $5$ came from the roots of the characteristic polynomial and tried the following approach:

Given $a,b\in\mathbb Z^+$ (for simplicity), and let $F_{a,b}:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be a function such that $F_{a,b}(0)=0$, $F_{a,b}(1)=1$ and $F_{a,b}(n+1)=a\cdot F_{a,b}(n)+b\cdot F_{a,b}(n-1)$.

> Conjecture:
>
> If $a,b$ are co-prime and $p>2$ is a prime that doesn't divide $b$, then
>
> $F_{a,b}\left(p-\left(\frac{a^2+4b}{p}\right)\right)\equiv 0\pmod p$,

Is this conjecture correct and known?

---

I have tested the conjecture with $50000$ randomly selected $a,b,p$. That is, three numbers $1\le a',b'\le 100$ and $3\le p'\le 10000$ are selected with uniform distribution, then
$a=\frac{a'}{gcd(a',b')},b=\frac{b'}{gcd(a',b')}$ and $p$ is set to the least prime $\ge p'$.

Comment: Your sequence is a Lucas sequence of the first kind. Your conjecture is true and well known. It is listed under "Other Relations" here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence .

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky. Yes, I found it. But the condition of the conjecture is not as hard $p\nmid b$ and on Wikipedia $p\nmid ab(a^2+4b)$. So far I have not found a counter-example of the condition in the conjecture.

Comment: The other conditions in the Wikipedia page are redundant, the proof does not require them. Your conditions suffice. I suspect that even requiring $a,b$ to be coprime is redundant.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky, you seems to be right. The co-prime condition was a faulty intuition: I immediately saw that there was something in the $a^2+4b$ but that some conditions was necessary. I have tested without the co-prime condition and with negative  $b$ ($a^2>4b$) and the only necessary condition seems to be that $p$ shouldn't divide $b$.